# Start a Service From a System Process

Tags: android

I'm trying to start a service, but I keep seeing the following message in the logcat output, which makes me question if things are really working:

```
W/ContextImpl( 1506): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: 
android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1479 
android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 
myapp.startService:765 
myapp.onStart:386 a
ndroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart:1171
```

My app is part of a platform build and installed in the **system directory**.  Right now I have this code for the Activity (starting the service from onStart):

```
public class MyAppNotification extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ...
        MyAppService.startService(MyAppNotification.this);
    }
}
```

The service then provides this function:

```
public class MyAppService extends Service {
    ...
    public static void startService(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAppService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

I will mention that previously the service was getting started by a broadcast receiver, but I would like to switch to starting it manually.

Finally, is this a problem of just not handling the context properly?